# Unwanted revert back to original of dbms.memory.heap.max_size

Tags: neo4j

I'm using Neo4j in a docker (v. 3.1.0). I tried to update the whole database with a single query when I faced error:

> There is not enough memory to perform the current task. Please try
>   increasing 'dbms.memory.heap.max_size' in the neo4j configuration
>   (normally in 'conf/neo4j.conf' or, if you you are using Neo4j Desktop,
>   found through the user interface) or if you are running an embedded
>   installation increase the heap by using '-Xmx' command line flag, and
>   then restart the database.

So I went to set the config file entries:

```
dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=512M
dbms.memory.heap.max_size=512M
```

I gave them both 2048M (as I've read [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/performance/#heap-sizing) that these two better to match). But after saving and restarting the docker, the entries are reverted back to their 512M original values. To make sure that it's not a docker issue, I wrote some comment line in the config, and it sticks. Which means the values are reverted by Neo4j intentionally. But why? Is it a limitation imposed by docker? Because my hardware has enough memory!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the standard docker image, the `/docker_entrypoint.sh` will set the memory based on environment variables or default it to 512M.

```
setting "dbms.memory.heap.initial_size" "${NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_maxSize:-512M}"
setting "dbms.memory.heap.max_size" "${NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_maxSize:-512M}"
```

When you instantiate your docker container add `--env NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_maxSize=2048` to the command.